# Editing a bot's discord message through promise chaining in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, discord.js

I'm currently working on a discord bot and one of the commands I'd like to implement is editing a message the bot has previously sent through using an `edit` command - I'm using [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) to do so and from the documentation, it looks like I'll need to use promise chaining to achieve what I want, but I'm a bit confused on some small pieces. My current code is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'edit',
    description: 'Edit one of the bot\'s messages',
    args: true, // does the command have arguments?
    guildOnly: true, // can this command be used outside of the discord channel?
    execute(message, args) {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            console.log("Insufficient arguments provided");
            return;
        }
        const server = message.guild;
        let id = args.shift();
        let newMessage = args.join(' ');

        let channels = server.channels;
        for (let [, channel] of channels) {
            if(channel.type === 'text') {
                channel.fetchMessage(id)
                .then(response => {
                    return response;
                }, _reason => {
                    console.log("still looking");
                })
                .then(function (message) {
                    message.edit(newMessage)
                    .then(editedMessage => {
                        console.log(`new message content: ${editedMessage}`);
                    })
                    .catch(console.error);
                })

            }
        }
    },
};
```

Essentially, my thought process is the following: the command can be used within any channel to edit any of the bot's messages in any other channel - to achieve this, I would need to cycle through all the server's channels and check for the appropriate message ID (as seen above with the for loop) - here is where I get confused, the `fetchMessage` command, seen [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessage) returns a promise, but my main concern is that if the message is **not** in the channel, I want the bot to continue looking until it finds it. Once it does, I try to chain another promise to actually [edit the message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=edit); at which point I would send a message to the discord that the process has successfully completed - as it stands now my code currently errors out once it checks the first channel and doesn't find the message, probably due to my rejection clause within the `fetchMessage` block. My question is: how do I get the program to not error out if it doesn't find the message on the first try and if it does find the right message, how do I get chain my promise to properly edit it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you add a `channel` argument, but if you really want to do it your way, you only need to catch `fetchMessage()`. Also, I don't understand the purpose of your first `.then()`. Here's how I would do it:

```
if (args.length < 2) {
  console.log("Insufficient arguments provided");
  return;
}
const server = message.guild;
let id = args.shift();
let newMessage = args.join(" ");

let channels = server.channels;
for (let [, channel] of channels) {
  if (channel.type === "text") {
    channel
      .fetchMessage(id)
      .then(message => {
        message.edit(newMessage).then(editedMessage => {
          console.log(`new message content: ${editedMessage}`);
        });
      })
      .catch(e => console.log("Not this channel"););
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I think I was getting turned around with the concept of promise chaining - I thought that nesting promises within one another was bad practice. (Hence why I returned the value and attempted to chain another `.then` outside of it)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's an array (or can be converted to Array) `message.guild.channels` can be scanned asynchronously by first forming a `.catch()` chain, built below with a pattern based on [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
module.exports = {
    'name': 'edit',
    'description': 'Edit one of the bot\'s messages',
    'args': true,
    'guildOnly': true,
    execute(message, args) {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            return Promise.reject(new RangeError('Insufficient arguments provided')); // ensure that execute() returns a Promise
        }
        let id = args.shift();
        let newMessage = args.join(' ');
        return message.guild.channels.reduce((rejetedPromise, [, channel]) => { // assuming `message.guild.channels` to be Array
            return rejetedPromise.catch(error => {
                if (channel.type === 'text') {
                    return channel.fetchMessage(id); // will resolve to `msg` if found and drop through to the then() below,
                                                     // otherwise will reject and flow will keep going to the next catch formed by the reduction.
                } else {
                    throw new Error('channel(s) searched but message not found'); // keep going to next catch
                }
            });
        }, Promise.reject('no channels')) // starter Promise for the reduction. If `message.guild.channels.length === 0`, this promise will fall straight through to the .catch() below
        .then(msg => msg.edit(newMessage)) // execution will arrive here only if a `channel.fetchMessage(id)` above succeeds.
        .then(editedMessage => { // this whole clause is optional.
            console.log(`new message content: ${editedMessage}`);
            return editedMessage; // return whatever is of interest to execute()'s caller.
        })
        .catch(error => { // this whole clause is optional.
            console.error(error);
            throw error; // rethrow error to inform execute()'s caller of the error.
        });
    }
};
```

The `message.guild.channels.reduce(...)` block deseves some explanation.

It construcs a catch chain, which if built manually would be of the form:

```
Promise.reject().catch(...).catch(...).catch(...).catch(...).then(...);
```

Compare that with the more familiar (and more easily understood) then chain:

```
Promise.resolve().then(...).then(...).then(...).catch(...);
```

The nature of the catch chain is that its settlement:

- will run from catch callback to catch callback as long as those callbacks either throw, or return a Promise that is/will be rejected.
- will skip to the final `.then()` as soon as any of the catch callbacks returns a value or a Promise that is/will be resolved.

Thus, you get exactly what you want - for the bot to continue looking in channel after channel until it finds the desired message.